# Divide by 0 error in Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I run this Query:

```
SELECT 
   [BBox]
  ,SUM(GrossPnL) AS 'Gross'
  ,SUM(SharesTraded) AS 'Shares'
  ,(SUM(GrossPnL)/SUM(SharesTraded)) AS 'CPS'
FROM [PrimusGroup].[dbo].[PrmsBlotter]
WHERE [RunType] = 'Backtesting'
GROUP BY [BBox]
```

I get divide by 0 error for cases where there's 0 shares traded.

I tried to fix this by:

```
SELECT 
   [BBox]
  ,SUM(GrossPnL) AS 'Gross'
  ,SUM(SharesTraded) AS 'Shares'
  ,(IF SUM(SharesTraded) > 0 
    (SUM(GrossPnL)/SUM(SharesTraded)) 
   ELSE 
     SUM(GrossPnL)) AS 'CPS'
FROM [PrimusGroup].[dbo].[PrmsBlotter]
WHERE [RunType] = 'Backtesting'
GROUP BY [BBox]
```

However I get Incorrect syntax near sum. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: why do you think there is an IF statement in SQL?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx

Comment: Why would you want to return the `sum()` if the denominator is 0?  `NULL` seems like a more sensible result in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `case` expression.

```
SELECT 
   [BBox]
  ,SUM(GrossPnL) AS 'Gross'
  ,SUM(SharesTraded) AS 'Shares'
  ,CASE WHEN SUM(SharesTraded) > 0 THEN SUM(GrossPnL)/SUM(SharesTraded)
   ELSE SUM(GrossPnL) END AS 'CPS'
FROM [PrimusGroup].[dbo].[PrmsBlotter]
WHERE [RunType] = 'Backtesting'
GROUP BY [BBox]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use IIF:

```
 SELECT 
       [BBox]
      ,SUM(GrossPnL) AS 'Gross'
      ,SUM(SharesTraded) AS 'Shares'
      ,(IIF SUM(SharesTraded) > 0, 
        (SUM(GrossPnL)/SUM(SharesTraded)), 
         SUM(GrossPnL)) AS 'CPS'
    FROM [PrimusGroup].[dbo].[PrmsBlotter]
    WHERE [RunType] = 'Backtesting'
    GROUP BY [BBox]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
SELECT [BBox]
  ,SUM(GrossPnL) AS 'Gross'
  ,SUM(SharesTraded) AS 'Shares'
  ,IIF(SUM(SharesTraded) > 0, SUM(GrossPnL)/SUM(SharesTraded), SUM(GrossPnL)) AS 'CPS'
FROM [PrimusGroup].[dbo].[PrmsBlotter]
WHERE [RunType] = 'Backtesting'
GROUP BY [BBox]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what the desired output is if the 'SharesTraded' = 0 but treating 0 and 1 as the same value (what you are doing above) seems wrong.

Assuming 0s are special cases, you case use the CASE WHEN situation and just make the 'ELSE' NULL but I like to use the 'NULLIF' function when possible.

So:

```
(SUM(GrossPnL)/SUM(SharesTraded)) AS 'CPS'
```

Becomes:

```
(SUM(GrossPnL)/NULLIF(SUM(SharesTraded),0)) AS 'CPS'
```

This will result in 'CPS' of NULL when 'SharesTraded' = 0 by setting SUM(SharesTraded) to 0, thus resolving the error.

Not sure what this looks like in the show-plan but it helps keep code clean and concise.

Comment: @Hogan No it will not... 'NULLIF' will replace the second value (in this case 0) with Null

Comment: SELECT
 0
 ,NULLIF(0,0)